# Enhancing a java object at runtime

Tags: java, proxy-classes, dynamic-proxy, javassist

I am aware that using proxy capable libraries (javassist, JDK dynamic proxies, etc) that it is possible to enhance a *class* to implement an interface at runtime.

My question is: is it possible to enhance an instantiated *object* to implement an interface at runtime (and likewise provide appropriate method handlers).

Comment: Could you describe a use-case where doing this helps? My suggestion would be to re-consider your design if you have to do this.

Comment: Agreed - if, for example, you're trying to write an app that can be upgraded in-place (or something similar) without needing to be restarted, there are better ways to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, we can't change a class that has already been loaded. And we can't replace a loaded class (within a classloader).

There *may* be a chance if you

- load a class with a custom classloader
- unload the classloader (should unload the class aswell)
- load the modified class again with a new classloader instance

But that is very, very black magic...